# Bluetooth - automatically disconnect after a few minutes?

Tags: fedora, bluetooth

I just upgraded to fedora 28, now my bluetooth headset automatically disconnect after a few minutes while using it.

Any idea how should I fix this?

Comment: This might be cause by the new power saving of fedora, is there way to disable that?

Comment: it seem it is working now

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Fedora 28 and a bluetooth mouse that disconnected - eventually fixed this problem by adding a udev rule (file) in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-bluetooth-mouse.rules with the contents:

```
#
#  stops power saving on bluetooth mouse
#  install in /etc/udev/rules.d/
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hid", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```